# Как считается градиент dE/Dw?

Tags: математика, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Скажите пожалуйста, каким образом берётся производная dE/dw (то что это производная сложной функции с помощью правила цепочки я знаю), а точнее откуда берутся дифференциалы по dy и ds? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]